# Не подключается css к html на django

Tags: python, django

Помогите пожалуйста! Не могу понять, почему не подключается css в html на django.
При запуске получаю только html, без css, в логе пишет:

```
[11/Mar/2020 15:52:53] "GET /static/web_site_design.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1683
[11/Mar/2020 15:52:53] "GET /static/laptop.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1656
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Дорожные решения</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "web_site_design.css" %}' type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
    <div id="rectangle"></div>
    <div id="rectangle1"></div>
    <div id="title">Дорожные<br/> решения</div>
    <div id="menu">
    <div class="menu_components">
        <form action='map/'>
        <button type="submit" class="m_button" id="map_b">Карта</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_components">
        <form action="feedback_page.html">
        <button type="submit" class="m_button">Подать жалобу</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_components">
        <form action='open_data.html'>
        <button type="submit" class="m_button">Открытые данные</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_components">
        <form action=''>
        <button type="submit" class="m_button">О проекте</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
    <br class="text"> <strong>Дорожные решения</strong> - инновационный проект,<br/>генерирующий рекомендации по улучшению<br/> безопасности дорожной ситуации и прогнозирующий<br/> будущее количество ДТП на основе алгоритмов <br/> машинного обучения и
    анализе данных.
    </div>
    <div><img src="{% static " laptop.png " %}" id='lapt'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

settings.py

```
import os
import sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'initiative.apps.InitiativeConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'KEM_DTP_ANALYSIS.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [PROJECT_ROOT + '\\templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'KEM_DTP_ANALYSIS.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Novosibirsk'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')abspath(__file__)))

    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/


    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'grappelli',
        'initiative.apps.InitiativeConfig',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'KEM_DTP_ANALYSIS.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [PROJECT_ROOT + '\\templates'],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'KEM_DTP_ANALYSIS.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]

    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

    TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Novosibirsk'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = "/static/"

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

Comment: Покажите код, как в шаблоне загружаете css

Comment: Я думаю стоит описать как вы подключали стили, настройки с settings.py как выводили в шаблоне html

Comment: файл css и лого лежит в корне папки static?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, да, в корне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему) Адресация сбилась из-за перемещения папок с приложениями, переписал всё, и заработало!